# Reverse engineering tools for Java web applications

Tags: java, javascript, netbeans, uml, reverse-engineering

I have been searching in the Internet looking for an application which could take a Netbeans Web project and create an UML diagram resulting from these classes. Also, but not essential, I would like a similar tool for the JavaScript code I have in the Java web project I mentioned before. It's such an inferno trying to understand the structure and inner relations of this web project I was given.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Visio](http://visiotoolbox.com) for creating UML diagrams by reverse engineering but I don't know whether it will work for JScript or not but you may give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Most UML tools have the capability to reverse engineer Java source into UML models.  Few of them will generate the diagrams automagically for you.  And none of them will know a thing about your view layer, so don't expect to see JSPs.

You may get class or package diagrams.  Sequence diagrams will be a challenge.

I know of no such thing for JavaScript code.

Answer (score 0):

Good UML tools:
Free - ArgoUML
Commercial - Enterprise Architect, MagicDraw

Javascript tool:
"Code Visual to Flowchart 3.5"
http://www.fileguru.com/Code-Visual-To-Flowchart/info

Answer (score 0):

This says it will UML diagram JS: http://jsuml.org/

That being said, JS is typically not object-oriented in the sort of way where UML diagrams are too likely to help.

Comment: You may find EventBug useful... a Firefox extension that goes along with Firebug and lets you see what JS event handlers are attached on the page: http://getfirebug.com/releases/extensions.html#eventbug

Answer (score 0):

Try this Open Source, Free and easy to use tool called [Star UML](http://staruml.sourceforge.net/en/) . It has all the features you need like reverse engineering and i use it a lot for that purpose .

Answer (score 0):

I used [Enterprise Arctitect](http://www.sparxsystems.com/products/ea/index.html) in previous projects.  It can reverse engineer your code into UML, XML you name it.  It can also do a lot more!  We used it to document the code functionality that was actually implemented so it could be compared with the original spec.

It's a great tool for Business Analysts, Project Managers, Software Architects and Engineers because it has tools for each of these users' perspectives.

Comment: Using EA version 7. It cannot reverse engineer Javascript code. Would like to know if any later releases of EA can do this and how good they are at it.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://www.uml-lab.com/en/uml-lab/. It provides reverse engineering of Java code. It will extract known patterns and provides a pattern template to match your project.